# Problema para mostrar datos desde mysql a modal con jsp y bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap, jsp

Tengo un problema para mostrar datos desde mysql en un modal con jsp y bootstrap
para invocar el modal , tengo un botón de tipo button, que es el que abre el modal, y en el modal, llegan datos desde la base de datos mysql.
El problema es que al presionar el botón para abrir el modal, el modal se visualizar solo su barra superior donde esta el titulo del modal,pero no muestra el cuerpo del modal , a menos que cambie el tipo de botón a submit, y despues a button nuevamente y al volver ejecutar el modal se muestra, pero solo temporalmente, ay que cuando se cierra la aplicación y se vuelve a ejecutar, vuelve a pasar el mismo problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui el codigo del botón que abre el modal

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalReserva2" name="btn_ver_reserva" width=10 heigth=10><img src="imagenes/img_ver_reserva.png" alt="x"/>Ver</button>
```

aquí está el modal donde llegan los datos.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalReserva2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title bg-primary" id="myModalLabel">Detalle Folio</h4>
                            <br>
                            <div class="container">
```

```
<%

                            try 
        {


            for(int i=0; i<reserva.size(); i++)
                    {



                                    out.println("<table");
                                    out.println("<tr>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-row' col-md-8>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-4'>");
                                    out.println("<label for='inputEmail4'>Numero de Reserva:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_numero_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getNumeroReserva()+"><br>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-4'>");
                                    out.println("<label for='inputPassword4'>Origen:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_origen_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getOrigenReserva()+"><br>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-4'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-4'>Destino:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_destino_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getDestinoReserva()+"><br>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-5'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-4'>Origen Vuelo:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_origen_vuelo_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getOrigenVueloReserva()+"><br>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    //out.println("</div>");
                                    //out.println("<div class='form-row' col-md-6>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-3'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-5'>Piezas Totales:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_total_piezas_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getTotalPiezasReserva()+"><br>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-3'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-5'>Kilos Totales:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_total_kilos_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getTotalKilosReserva()+"><br>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-3'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-5'>Volumen Total:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_total_volumen_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getTotalVolumenReserva()+"><br>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-5'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-5'>Estado:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='estado' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_estado_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getEstadoReserva()+"><br>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-5'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-5'>Fecha Creación:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_fecha_creacion_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getFechaCreaciónReserva()+"><br>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-5'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-5'>Fecha Embarque:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_fecha_embarque_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getFechaEmbarqueReserva()+"><br>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-5'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-5'>Tipo Reserva:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_tipo_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getTipoReserva()+"><br>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-5'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-5'>Prioridad:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_prioridad_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getPrioridadReserva()+"><br>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-4'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-4'>Tipo Tarifa:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_tipo_tarifa_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getTipoTarifaReserva()+"><br>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-2'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-2'>Tarifa:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_tarifa_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getTarifaReserva()+"><br>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-2'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-2'>Tipo Moneda:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_tipo_moneda_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getTipoMonedaReserva()+"><br>");                                                   
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-5'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-5'>Notas:</label><br><textarea type='text' class='form-control' rows='5' id='notas' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_notas_reserva' value="+reserva.get(i).getNotaReserva()+"></textarea><br>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("</div>");












                    }

                for(int i=0; i<cliente.size(); i++)
                {                   

                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-2'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-2'>Cliente:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_codigo_cliente' value="+cliente.get(i).getCodigoCliente()+"><br>");  
                }                   out.println("</div>");

                for(int i=0; i<usuario.size(); i++)
                {                   
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-2'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-2'>Usuario:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_id_usuario' value="+usuario.get(i).getIdUsuario()+"><br>");  
                                    out.println("</div>");
                }       
                for(int i=0; i<folio.size(); i++)
                {
                                    out.println("<div class='form-group col-md-2'>");
                                    out.println("<label class='form-group col-md-2'>Folio:</label><br><input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputPassword' placeholder='Origen' name='txt_id_folio' value="+folio.get(i).getIdFolio()+"><br>");  
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("</div>");
                                    out.println("</tr>");
                                    out.println("</table>");
                }
```

}
                   catch(Exception e)
                    {

```
                                    out.close();

                }

              %>

 </table>                                            

</form>                

                            </div>
```

```
              </div>
            </div>

    </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Hola Simón, siento que tu pregunta será mejor recibida por la comunidad si creas un [mcve]

Comment: Ok agregaré este problema con mas detalla e imágenes.

Answer (score 0):

yo lo hago con javascript, en la parte de boton tiene que añadir los datos por ejemplo:

el div del modal lo defino

```
 <div id="massModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

    <input type='text' 
class='form-control' 
id='descripcion_mass' 
maxlength='255'  required='required' autofocus>
```

en la parte de boton estaria asi  botón 
      
      Ver

declaro una funcion que me muestre un modal

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     // Show a post
            $(document).on('click', '.massshow-modal', function() {
                $('.modal-descripcion').text('Vista de los Datos');

                  //el #id_mass corresponder el id de input
                $('#id_mass').val($(this).data('id'));
    $('#descripcion_mass').val($(this).data('descripcion'));
    $('#id_tipo_mass').val($(this).data('id_tipo'));
    $('#id_estado_mass').val($(this).data('id_estado'));
    $('#created_at_mass').val($(this).data('created_at'));
    $('#updated_at_mass').val($(this).data('updated_at'));
    $('#usuarios_id_mass').val($(this).data('usuarios_id'));
    ;

                //me muestra el modal en bootstrap 
                $('#massModal').modal('show');
                $('#acciones').attr('class', 'btn btn-info hibe');
                $('#acciones').text('Visible');
                $('#acciones').attr('disabled');

            });
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias lo intentaré y te cuento